# Book called “The Inheritors” from 70s or 80s

Tags: story-identification, novel, apocalypse

I’m convinced I read a book called “*The Inheritors*” about two kids living in a post apocalyptic society. I don’t know the author and all searches on this title find other books that aren’t it…

It's actually very similar to “*This Time of Darkness*” by Suzanne Martel, but after reading that I’m sure it’s not the one.

The book I’m seeking ends when the girl travels through the tunnels and nearly dies, then opens the door and finds the air is actually breathable and it’s safe. It’s a full book and not a short story…
If anyone has any idea I would appreciate to know the author.

Comment: Although the answer has been found, something about your question is still unclear; you appear to have conflated two different works.  Did you mean that *The Inheritors* was similar to *The City Under Ground* by Suzanne Martel or *This Time of Darkness* by H. M. Hoover?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that's the one. I wrote it, and it was published by the University of Queensland Press as one of its early YA titles. Nice to know people still remember it :-) It's been out of print for ages.
-Jill

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. The 'Your Answer' field should only be used to answer the question though, not merely to comment on it or previous answers. When you've earned enough [reputation](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) to unlock the [comment everywhere](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) privilege, you can leave comments beneath other users' questions or answers. Take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more.

Comment: Since you probably have a copy of the book around, you could make this a good answer by including a few brief quotes matching the scenes described in the question, like the tunnel or finding the air breathable.

Comment: Wow! A comment from THE AUTHOR! Thank you so much. That blew my mind. I have most certainly remembered your book, I’ve been trying to track down a copy of it for years, I loved it when I read it, but it was a library copy and had to be returned. I was never able to locate it again. Now I want to re read it as an adult and also let my children read it. Thank you so much for responding !

Comment: Jill, do you know where I could purchase it or do you have any for sale? 
Or better yet, do you plan to publish to kindle?

Comment: Hi Amanda. I'm really touched that you've remembered it all these years and that you've been trying to find a copy for your children. I don't have any spares myself - it's so long ago that it was published, and I gave copies away over the years. It had a long life in the library system (hurrah for libraries!). I am actually thinking of relaunching it in Kindle, as a first step into self-publishing. If and when I do, I'll set up an author page so people can find me. -Jill (Claudia-398)

Answer (score 13):

Perhaps [*The Inheritors*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/4986933-the-inheritors) by Jill Dobson, first published in 1988

It’s post-apocalyptic, and the protagonist is a teenage girl.

> Twenty-five years after a nuclear war, a community of survivors live
> on beneath a protective dome. Sixteen-year-old Claudia, a promising
> youth leader, begins to question her society's oppressive values and
> wonders about the dome's security.
>
> [image]

Comment: Thanks! Now I can try to locate it. It’s been bugging me for years, would you believe!